# Using php sockets for HTML 5 canvas and javascript games

Tags: javascript, php, html, sockets, canvas

I'm trying to create a game called tanks which will be a multiplayer game. I'm trying to use PHP sockets mentioned on the php manual website. And HTML 5 canvas javascript to move the tanks and fire bullets in the game. My question is should I use ajax way to transfer data or should I use sockets ? I don't know to use sockets please suggest faster and better alternative way.

[Link to my code repository on Github](https://github.com/resheilA/Tanks)

Comment: "should I use ajax way to transfer data or should I use sockets"  -- Unfortunately this opinion-based question is off topic for SO.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be better for this question

Comment: Its not about opinion, its about experience !  I don't want my game to lag using any one of the technology. Ones who have already tried anyone of these can tell me why and how !